# How to display HttpResponseMessage on the view after update grid data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid

This is my controller.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage PostContactPerson(Model model)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          var isExists= true
          if (isExists)
          {
             ModelState.AddModelError("Error", @"This email is already used");
             return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, ModelState);
           }            
    }
}
```

I am developing `asp.net` project using `Telerik platform`. I used `Kendo grid` to display data with web API.when update grid data, I want to display return message on my view which return from web API controller. Can any one help?

Comment: Please, add your code